# Python Pandas merge right join on first match

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge, join

I have two data frames

The first frame is my IDs, some 'old code' matches to one 'Master ID'. Some OLD code are not matched to a Master ID.

**ID Dataframe**

```
MASTER ID  OLD CODE 

  MASTER1    1A
  MASTER1    1B
  MASTER2    2
  MASTER3    3
             4
```

**Sales**

```
OLD CODE  Salesvalues  
1A         10           
1B         15           
2           6           
3           8   
4           5
```

If I am doing a right join or an outer join, it returns more rows then my original sales table. How I can make a join **on the first matching 'MASTER ID'** match and keeping the same number of rows(no multiple duplicate rows). I would like if there is no match for the'old code' on 'master ID', that will returns NA.

**Expected Merge dataframe**

```
  OLD CODE  Salesvalues  MASTER ID (Join column) 
    1A         10           MASTER1
    1B         15           MASTER1
    2           6           MASTER2
    3           8           MASTER3
    4           5             NA
```

Comment: Please see the update. If I do this it returns more rows then my sales dataframe and I want to add the NA match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you.

```
Sales.merge(ID Dataframe,on='OLD_CODE',how ='outer')
```

Comment: I have a data frame of sales of 4209900 rows and a dataframe of ID which do not have all Master ID matching. If I applied this code, it returns me 14145 rows. I cannot use a inner join because i want my 4209900 rows with some matching Master ID or NA

Comment: calls = pd.merge(sales, ID Dataframe, on= "old code", how= "left"), return 4223111 rows instead of 4209900

Comment: can you use the merge exactly as i have put & check? With the data you have provided, i get the result you are expecting.